# Help me with differential equation of harmonic motion.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I asked this question before, but I don't quite understand it.

So the question is

A particle undergoes simple harmonic motion. Initially its displacement is 1 , velocity 1

and acceleration is -12. and find out displacement and acceleration when the velocity is

square root of 8.

Someone says that harmonic equation takes the form y(t)=Acos(Wt+@)

But, I can not solve this equation by taking derivative and putting in the values//

Someone help me plz

Comment: It was a long ago that he might not care..?